# How to read a cell value with multiple decimals using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

When I enter a value of `0,003` in my Ecxel document, the value I get back in my code is `3.0000000000000001E-3` with a `DataType` of null. When I use `0,03` as a value, everyhing works as expected. So the problem is using more than 2 decimals.

How can I fix this? Here's the code I'm using:

```
    private string GetCellValue(Cell cell)
    {
        var stringTablePart = _excelDocument.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
        var value = cell?.CellValue?.InnerXml;

        if (cell?.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
        {
            return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[int.Parse(value)].InnerText;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Comment: I guess the comma and dot are typos and should be `0,03`?

Comment: @JvdV Yes indeed, i've updated my post. Thanks.

Comment: I expect this has noting to do with your code but rather with how Excel tries to convert the number in the cell to binary and back.